# OverflowException on Integer Addition

Tags: vb.net

Aight so whenever I run this code in an online compiler, it tells me:

> "Exception in user code: System.OverflowException: Arithmetic
>   operation resulted in an overflow. at Rextester.Program.Main(String[]
>   args)".

Now is this a problem with the compiler not being able to understand my equation or is it with my code?

```
Public Sub Main(args() As string)           

    Dim X as Integer
    Dim counter as Integer          

    X=5

    Do 
        counter=counter+1 
        X=X+X
    Loop until counter>120 

    Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!")
End Sub
```

Comment: For future reference, "Need help please" is not an acceptable title. The title should be a concise summary of your issue. We should know the sort of thing we're in for without ever opening the thread. You should spend some time in the Help Center to learn what constitutes a good question. That you have no badges indicates that you didn't even take the tour when prompted to at registration. Please make the effort to help us help you by learning how to use the site properly.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of a signed Integer is `2147483647`. If that value overflows, an exception is thrown to prevent unexpected behavior of your program.

**Solution**: Use an `Int64` for your X `variable`. With a max value of `9223372036854775807`

Comment: An Int64 isn't big enough for 13292279957849158729038070602803445760. You could suggest using a [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8) from `System.Numerics` ;)